# unable to test login fragment using espresso in android

Tags: android, kotlin, testing

i am a newbie to android testing. i am trying to test a login fragment which has email and password fields and a login button. when i click on that button i should get redirected to a dashboard fragment. here is code for the test->

```
@RunWith(JUnit4::class)
@LargeTest
class LoginSuccessTest {

    private lateinit var scenario: FragmentScenario<LoginFragment>

    //run the login fragment
    @Before
    fun setupTestEnvironment() {
        scenario = launchFragment()
        scenario.moveToState(Lifecycle.State.STARTED)
    }

    @Test
    public fun loginSuccess()
    {
        //enter email and password
        onView(withId(R.id.emailEt)).perform(typeText("abc@gmail.com"))

        onView(withId(R.id.passwordEt)).perform(typeText("abctest123"))

        //close on-screen keyboard
        Espresso.closeSoftKeyboard()

        //click on sign in button
        onView(withId(R.id.login)).perform(click())

        // successful login moves user to next screen
        val scenarioDashboardFragment = launchFragment<DashboardFragment>()
        scenarioDashboardFragment.moveToState(Lifecycle.State.STARTED)

    }

}
```

when i run this test i get an error related to creating fragment view->

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #42 in //fragment layout file
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 1: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f030008 a=-1}
```

can anyone help and please tell me if there is something wrong with code or logic?
the code is written in kotlin language.